# curl to coldfusion cfhttp

Tags: curl, coldfusion, railo

I am trying to make this curl to cfhttp, but unable to get this done

```
C:\>curl -k https://api.juspay.in/order/create -u 320EABE1225D45E6B13DF5D3D2BBDB80: -d "amount=10.00"
```

response:

```
{
"status": "CREATED",
"status_id": 1,
"order_id": null
}
```

coldfusion script:

```
  <cfhttp url='https://api.juspay.in/order/create'  username="320EABE1225D45E6B13DF5D3D2BBDB80" password="" method="post" >
        <cfhttpparam name="amount" type="formField" value="10">
    </cfhttp>
```

Getting below response, while hitting through cfhttp

```
  { "status": "error", "error_code": "access_denied" }
```

but the curl was working fine.

Comment: Do you have a valid username and password? The error would suggest you don't have access.

Comment: yes they are correct, I got the output when I tried with curl

Comment: In the CURL example, the value of product_id is ":pid", but in the CFHTTP version it is just "pid". Missing a colon? Also, I hope that isn't your valid API key.

Comment: updated the code with curl output, all the fields are not required, using the same username in both the snippets

Comment: Have you added the SSL Cert for juspay.in to the java certificate store? You can use http://certman.riaforge.org/index.cfm to make this easier to do. You should simplify your test and try a `cfhttp` request to `https://api.juspay.in/img/logo.png` too see if you have any connectivity to the site at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate - OP resolved this issue and reported as such here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/24933746/1636917