# How to send header info in cfhttpparam

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfhttp, cfhttpparam

I have been given the following directions to pull a JSON list of data from a webservice.

```
GET /criminal_api/1.0/service/requests
HTTP Header: Authorization: Bearer 6EDC52118E164AE659EA2C772F3B9804
```

The following values in the header `Bearer 6EDC52118E164AE659EA2C772F3B9804` are dynamic and will be set using the following `content` variable

```
 <cfset content = deserializeJSON(    {
       "access_token": "84F224956C6AB5287038C0209EBAC5AB",
       "token_type": "bearer",
       "refresh_token": "E48BB9C164FE2125D3BE2CD602E4A692",
       "expires_in": 7199,
       "scope": "read write"
    })>
```

So I am tried the following:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="https://test.mywebsite.com/criminal_api//1.0/service/requests" result="orderList">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Authorization" value="#content.token_type# #content.access_token#">
</cfhttp>
```

But when I check the filecontent instead of getting a JSON list I get: `Connection Failure`

I have a feeling it is how I am setting the header value I am just not sure what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT:**
When I added a ":" in between the token type and access token I got a new error:

```
struct
error   -1
error_description   Invalid access token: : 82D773278FB69CFBCFB4CB8CEF8AC03D
```

Obviously it thinks the ":" is part of the access token so it is connecting I am just not sure how to have both values in the value= field so it is read correctly.

Comment: Connection failure typically means you are not making a connection at all. If it where something to do with a required header or content issue I would expect a different message. Check to see if:

A) you your cert is installed in the keystore - that Java can handshake with the site in question using SSL/TLS

B) That the server is correctly resolving the IP address.

Comment: Mark the previous cfhttp get to the same address to pull the access_token JSON data was able to connect with no issues. Only when I hit the same url but a different method "requests" and I am supposed to pass the info in the previous call in the header do I get the no connection failure. Sorry I am not sure if I understand about the JAVA since I am doing this in coldfusion. please explain and I would be happy to follow up on that. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I added an edit to my question which may help narrow down what is going on.

Comment: How particular is the webservice?  The directions show a capital 'B' for the token type `Bearer` but your example is passing a lower case 'b' for the token type `bearer`.

Comment: I am spitting it back to its self. The first call to the webservice gets the bearer term in that case I just save it to a variable. So i kept it that way. Do you think the deserializeJSON would change the case?

Comment: No I do not think deserializeJSON would change the case. I am just going by the information that you provided. One is upper and the other lower. `HTTP Header: Authorization: Bearer 6EDC52118E164AE659EA2C772F3B9804` versus `"token_type": "bearer",`

Comment: RE my first comment - if you can make _any_ successful TLS connection to the URL then you are ok with the cert issue and can disregard my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="https://test.mywebsite.com/criminal_api//1.0/service/requests" result="orderList" username="#content.token_type#" password="#content.access_token#">
```

This will produce an authorization header of "Basic Bearer:6EDC52118E164AE659EA2C772F3B9804"

Manually, that would be:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="https://test.mywebsite.com/criminal_api//1.0/service/requests" result="orderList">
<cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Authorization" value="Basic #content.token_type#:#content.access_token#">
```

There's also the question of what that hex value contains.  Take a look at [Getting Basic Authentication to work with ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933746/getting-basic-authentication-to-work-with-coldfusion) - maybe this more closely reflects your situation.