# How to create the ColdFusion Equivalent to Curl Question

Tags: curl, coldfusion

I am trying to repeat the following cURL Example using CFHTTP/CFHTTPPARAM but no luck

```
    curl https://your-space.signalwire.com/api/relay/rest/jwt \
  -X POST \
  -u 'YourProjectID:YourProjectToken' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

I've tried appending the #YourProjectID#:#YourProjectToken# directly to the URL, that didnt work..

Here is my CFHTTP code;

```
<cfhttp method="post" url="#u#" >
    <cfhttpparam  type="url" name="#projectID#" value="#APItoken#"> 
    <cfhttpparam  type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
</cfhttp>
```

ANy suggestions on how to structure this?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933746/getting-basic-authentication-to-work-with-coldfusion

Answer (score 2):

If you currently have:

```
<cfset u = "https://your-space.signalwire.com/api/relay/rest/jwt" />
```

try to ***prepend*** the authentication credentials to the url, like:

```
<cfset u = "https://" & #projectID# & ":" & #APItoken# & "@your-space.signalwire.com/api/relay/rest/jwt" />
<cfhttp method="post" url="#u#" >
    <cfhttpparam  type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
</cfhttp>
```

Another thing you could try would be:

```
<cfset u = "https://your-space.signalwire.com/api/relay/rest/jwt" />
<cfhttp 
    method="post" 
    url="#u#" 
    username="#projectID#"
    password="#APItoken#" >

    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
    
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Alex Baban; Hey thanks for the reply, but that unfortunately did not work...  the result form CFHTTP is the same...

Comment: Thanks Alex, trying your suggestion; I get

Comment: {"code":400,"message":"JSON you submitted is not valid: 785: unexpected token at 'username=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%%2Da69e45e90ec5\u0026password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'","more_info":"https://signalwire.com","status":400}

Comment: Just looking at this last response, I wonder if request is URL encoding the - dash marks

Comment: I've updated again the "Another thing you could try" code.

Comment: Alex, that worked... Thanks for your help... I can go to bed now... lol...

Comment: I would give you some points, but not qualified to give points yet... Thanks Alex...